# ngMeta + google search

Tags: angularjs

I bet this is a quick one but what would be the default Google search result for a page that creates the tags dynamically? I was checking [Angular Dynamic meta tags in head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381918/angular-dynamic-meta-tags-in-head/32152701#32152701) and also reading about http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngMeta which is really useful to change, in my case, the title of the SPA. However I first tried with a factory and the google results were showing as `{{myFactory.getTitle()}}` which is unexpected.

First of all I don't know if that's possible and secondly I don't know if that can be achieved with ngMeta.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [demo site](http://vinaygopinath.github.io/ngMeta) for help setting up ngMeta in your app.

Using this in your HTML should show the title properly in Google search results. (`title` instead of `getTitle()`)

```
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{ngMeta.title}}" />
```