# How to change meta data and title dynamically depending upon the URL in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, html, metadata

I want to set my Title and Meta Data dynamically depending upon my URLs location (slug). I have tried 'ngMeta' but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a controller for the header and use data binding.

Comment: Hope this link helps: [Dynamic Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381918/angular-dynamic-meta-tags-in-head)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.