# How to set dynamic meta data in every page using UI-Route in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, metadata

I am working on an application that is built in AngularJs but I am facing some issues with setting meta title, name, description dynamically. I tried "ui.router.metatags" but the problem is meta title, name, description are not showing when I view source code in any browser. It is only show as {{meta.title}} not the actual data that is injected.

Here is my code:

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: "/",
    metaTags: {
        title: 'title1',
        description: 'description',
        keywords: 'keyword1,keyword2,...',
        properties: {
            'og:title': 'title1'
        }
    },
    views : {
        "" : {
            templateUrl:"/home/home.html",
            controller: 'homeCtrl',
            controllerAs:'vm',
        }
    },

    resolve: {
        loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('home'); // Resolve promise and load before view
        }]
    }
})
```

Here is the index file code :

```
<title ng-bind="MetaTags.title">{{MetaTags.title}}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{MetaTags.description}}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{{MetaTags.keywords}}">
```

Comment: `MetaTags` and `metaTags` is different. Is this is a typo mistake ?

Comment: No. I found this in tutorial. So I don't think is a  typo mistake

Comment: have you included the library script?

Comment: Yes I have done everything to set Meta Tags and all but still unable to do the thing

Comment: check the last answer here ([Angular Dynamic meta tags in head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381918/angular-dynamic-meta-tags-in-head))

Comment: I am using UI-Route, and I already check this solution. It's giving me the same error