# Angularjs 1.5 ng-controller on the <head> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo

I'm using Angularjs 1.5.

Created a service to handle a META data and page title.
trying to apply it.

The issue is - for some reason if i define a controller directly on the `<head>` tag:

`<head ng-controller="headMetaController">`

the controller will not be loaded at all, but if i wrap it in additional `<div>` withing the `<head>`:

```
<head>
<div ng-controller="headMetaController">
    <title ng-bind="seoMetaService.title()"></title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ seoMetaService.metaDescription() }}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ seoMetaService.metaKeywords() }}">
<div>
</head>
```

=> it works.

So, i guess its somehow connected with particularly `<head>` tag => not sure, what is the right way to solve it?
i'm also do afraid that putting the meta data within the additional `<div>` may not be a good idea for SEO purposes?

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: Move `ng-controller` to your `<html>` tag. You'll have both `ng-app` and `ng-controller` on that tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about SEO, you're going to have to approach this from another angle.

In addition to `<div>` not being valid inside of `<head>`, using interpolation on `<meta>` values is a red flag. The crawlers who care about these tags, won't see them—instead they'll see `{{ seoMetaService.metaKeywords()}}`, which is obviously bad for SEO.

Solution A: Render these values server side.

Solution B: Keep what you have, but instruct crawlers to access your page at a different location. Add `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`, and allow a *snapshot* of your rendered page to live elsewhere—and be served up when `?_escaped_fragment_=` is added to the URL. You can delegate this part to services like [prerender.io](http://prerender.io) or similar, which will scan and store your pages.

Comment: `{{ seoMetaService.metaKeywords()}}` but this kind of thing is suppose to be rendered, not? as i understand google is partially supports js frameworks now, not?

Comment: For the most part, bots and scrapers that are crawling for meta data—don't run javascript. For example, if you pasted the URL of the site in the share box on Facebook, it would show the `{{foo.title}}`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i think `<div>` is not a valid tag to be inside of the `<head>` tag since the  tag is only meant to be for metadata, scripts, styles, and other stuff which isn't meant to be displayed.

Secondly, even though you call the controller like this it doesn't mean you can access controller variables inside `head` tag. Only service/factories can invoke inside `head` tag.

So instead of calling it from `head` tag call the controller from `html` tag or `body` tag or inside body tag

Comment: ok, thanks about `div`.
about the controller - it is just not getting initialized if i use it on `head` tag. `html` tag - i have another controller there for global functions..

Comment: controllers in head tag actually not getting initialized. that is why instead of controllers we use service to access data inside head tag.  you can have nested controllers inside the body tag.

Comment: controllers in head - clear, thanks.
but how can i use a service directly in html without having a controller as middleware? googling shows that i have to bind a service intro the controller's `$scope` variable.

Comment: check this answer i think you will get a idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119398/how-can-i-update-meta-tags-in-angularjs?answertab=active#tab-top