# How to modify HTMLElement in index.html before page gets returned to requestor

Tags: angularjs, facebook, typescript, ionic-framework, deep-linking

Based on my custom URL parameters I process, I am trying to modify dynamically a meta tag I have id'ed in index.html like so:

```
<meta name="og:image" content="http://example.com/someurl.jpg" id="ogImage"/>
```

The code below in my home.ts seems to be working

```
document.getElementById('ogImage').setAttribute("content", Media.ImageURL) ;
```

I can verify it is via the browser dev console/elements.

However, when I view from facebook via their ojbect graph debugger at
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

It appears to see the default

```
http://example.com/someurl.jpg
```

as if the index.html is shipped before my home.ts gets chance to make the update.

Perhaps, my understanding is flawed and there is better way to do this.
Thank you.

**Note1:** initially, I was thinking I had to make some angular binding between index.html and one of my services but I could not locate any sample code, the closest I came to was this post
[How can I update meta tags in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119398/how-can-i-update-meta-tags-in-angularjs)
But I don't know how to apply it for my ionic2/3 code, so I opted for the document.get approach.

**Note2:** the ultimate goal here is to share a link into a social media (web or app) like facebook, a messenger like viber/skype, etc... and have it resolve to meaningful images, title, description to drive the visit back to the site via browser, or app if the user clicking on the link is on a mobile device with my app version of the site installed on his device.

**Note3:** if you decide to point me to ionic deeplinking please provide code to match above, because I could not understand how to apply to my case.

Comment: You can not set Open Graph meta tags with client-side JavaScript, the Facebook scraper does not care for that. They must be contained in the HTML code returned by your server.

Comment: @CBroe  I don't have experience with server side javascript, so you are telling me that unlike a browser who executes the page scripts, the facebook scrapper purely looks at the html only. Perhaps, you could explain to me the flow of things works, facebook request url, 2) some where JS executes processes my custom params 3) how will it communicate with the ionic stuff?  Thank you

Comment: @CBroe Oh probably I am confusing two separate interactions: pasting the URL into facebook causes a separate trip to my site.  and then visiting the site via the same URL is what I have already coded on the ionic client TS code.  Any pointers on the server side of thing will be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to implement **dynamic** open graph meta tags values in your pages, you will need a server-side scripting language like php.  Such a script will run on the server, update the pages as needed, then the pages will be served to the requesting site or application.

client-side scripting (ie. JavaScript) is usually ignored when a site or app is merely visiting your site/link for the purpose of extracting (aka scrapping, parsing html) information such as the one provided by the open graph meta tags (og:title, og:description og:image...).