# How to add Twitter summary Card for Dynamic Views?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working a website in Laravel and AngularJS. I wrote below meta tags in my site. I need to get dynamic values in AngularJS. Please help me.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE OF YOUR POST OR PAGE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION OF PAGE CONTENT" />
<meta property="og:image" content="LINK TO THE IMAGE FILE" />
<meta property="og:url" content="PERMALINK" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE NAME" />
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119398/how-can-i-update-meta-tags-in-angularjs

Comment: angularJs is front end framework so you are not supposed to use it to dynamic the meta tags, use back end scripts...

Answer (score 0):

Use like

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{{metaInformation.title}}">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{{metaInformation.description}}">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{{metaInformation.image}}">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="{{metaInformation.site}}">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="{{metaInformation.creater}}" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="{{metaInformation.url}}" />
```

and you can load metaInformation object from your basecontroller and change when ever you want.

But for a single page web application, you need to use some another tool like prerender (https://prerender.io/) to SEO