# Page title in ui routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am using ui route. I want to set the page title if the title is static or hard code, it's working fine but I want to set the page title based on dynamic state. Here is my code:

```
    .state('sportsbrief', {
    url: '/sportsbrief',
    controller: 'homeController as home',
    templateUrl: HTML.SPORTS_BRIEF,
    title:"sportsbrief"
  })
  .state('page',{
    url:'/page/:page',
    templateUrl:function(value){
      return"views/"+value.page+".html"
    },
    controller:"staticPageController",
    title:value.page

  })
```

I want to set the page title for state page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating title tag using AngularJS and UI-Router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183222/updating-title-tag-using-angularjs-and-ui-router)

Comment: @shankulkarni.....for sportsbrief state page title is appearing, i want to se t for state page on the basis of dynamic url defining in route

Comment: please check:
https://github.com/nonplus/angular-ui-router-title


$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    ...
    resolve: {
      // Constant title
      $title: function(val) { return val; }
    }
  })

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-ui-router-title in your app which allows dynamic title update.
https://github.com/nonplus/angular-ui-router-title

Ref: [Updating title tag using AngularJS and UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183222/updating-title-tag-using-angularjs-and-ui-router)