# Angular UI-Router Not Changing Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have code and I am trying to figure out the best way to have pages with their own title. Currently in the `index.html` it sets the title and somehow every page auto-inherits the title.

**index.html snippet**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Application</title>

...
```

The issue is for some reason I can't just go to a different page and type `<title>This Window Section</title>` in the `<head>` because it will still say "My Application". I've read around the it is possible to just add the title to the `$stateProvider` and it will change it but that doesn't change the title either.

**applicationUIRoutes.js snippet**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    ...
    $stateProvider.state("application.graph", {
         url: "/graph",
         views: {
             templateUrl: "apps/graph.html",
             controller: "graphController",
             controllerAs: "graphCtrl"
        },
        title: "Graph", // <-- Doesn't do anything. Page still says 'My Application'
    }
    
...
}
```

**graph.html snippet**

```
<head>
    <title>Graph</title> <!-- Doesn't work -->
    
...
```

What does work is setting it in the `graphController.js` and calling it in the html using `ng-init`. I don't want to have to do it this way (and I am pretty sure this is horrible and "hacky").

**graphController.js snippet**

```
... 

function _setWindowTitle(title) {
    document.title = title;
}

...
```

**graph.html snippet**

```
<head>
    <div ng-init="graphCtrl.setWindowTitle("Graph");"></div> <!-- Works -->
    
...
```

Is there a way to maintain having the default `index.html` title be there and be able to override it without doing it my hacky way? I preferably want to do it in my `applicationUIRoutes` but I would be fine with just being able to type `<title> title of something </title>` in a page and have that properly override the `index.html`.

## **--UPDATED ATTEMPTS--**

I have tried following [Set Page title using UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813599/set-page-title-using-ui-router) and [Updating title tag using AngularJS and UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183222/updating-title-tag-using-angularjs-and-ui-router) as a guide and added the following:

**applicationModule.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp, [ " ..
]);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$state = $stateParams;
}]);
```

**applicationUIRoutes.js snippet**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    ...
    $stateProvider.state("application.graph", {
         url: "/graph",
         views: {
             templateUrl: "apps/graph.html",
             controller: "graphController",
             controllerAs: "graphCtrl"
        },
        data: " { pageTitle: "Graph Test" }
    }
    
...
}
```

**graph.html snippet**

```
<head>
    <title ng-bind="$state.current.data.pageTitle></title>
```

But it still doesn't change the title. One thing I have noticed which is probably the issue is when inspecting in browser the actual code, it shows in the `<head>` that the title is "My Application (from `index.html`). And if I search the title I created is placed somewhere in the body as...

```
<div class="ng-scope" ui-view="">
    <title class="ng-scope"> Graph Title </title>
</div>
```

Not sure with why this is happening. I imagine it is how the code is structured when using views but I have tried adding the title in different parts of the `applicationUIRouter` and it still doesn't change.

Comment: [update the title using ui-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183222/updating-title-tag-using-angularjs-and-ui-router)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Page title using UI-Router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813599/set-page-title-using-ui-router). If this didn't help you try using [ng-page-title](https://github.com/riggerthegeek/ng-page-title)

Comment: I just tried putting the `$rootScope.on("$routeChangeSuccess", ... ` with the `<title ng-bind=` in the `graph.html` but it still results in the `My Application` title from the `index.html`.

Comment: I have updated my question with suggested attempts. Added possible reasoning as to why it isn't working.