# Using variables in AngularJS $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, the snippet for a dictionary site I'm building looks like this:

```
.when('/dictionary/:word2lookup', {
            title: 'The MySite dictionary',
            templateUrl : 'pages/dictionary.html',
            controller  : 'dictController'
        })
```

`word2lookup` is, as the name suggests, the word user enters in the input box and hits the submit button for a translation. When the translated data is rendered in the div below, the URL is programmed to reflect the word like so (say, the user is looking up the word, *cortar*):

> www.mysite.com/dictionary/cortar

However, regardless of the word being looked up, as long as the user stays on this page, the title remains static, i.e. `The PeppyBurro dictionary`). Is there any way I could pass on the variable `word2lookup` to the `$routeProvider` and get it to render a dynamic title like `Translation of cortar | The MySite Dictionary`?

I tried `'Translation of :word2lookup | The MySite Dictionary'` and it failed. I also tried `'Translation of' + :word2lookup + ' | The MySite Dictionary'` with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular using $routeParams in Page title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831660/angular-using-routeparams-in-page-title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to listen to every route change and respectively setting the document title. But many other options are possible by accessing `$route.current.params['word2lookup']`

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$route', '$location', function($rootScope, $route, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        if(0 === $location.path().indexOf('/dictionary/')) {
            document.title = 'Translation of ' + $route.current.params['word2lookup'] + ' | ' + $route.current.title;
    });
}]);
```