# Proper way to display view name

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute

I would like to display the view name above the view
Basically, I am looking for something like

```
<h1>{{viewName}}<h1>
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

I have tried convoluted ways to get the view name from $routeProvider without much success.
My router looks like this

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("myModule", ["ngRoute"]);

  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/view1", {
        name: "View One",
        templateUrl: "view1.html",
        controller: "View1Controller"
      })
      .when("/view2", {
        name: "View Two",
        templateUrl: "view2.html",
        controller: "View2Controller"
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/view1"
      });
  });

}());
```

My reasoning for displaying the view name outside the view is that the container (in this case ) would not be removed from the DOM at each view change, otherwise it flickers.
**Am I using the right approach? How do you reach the "name" property inside $routeProvider?**

Comment: What makes you think routes have names? They don't. Angular will ignore the name attribute that you have added to the route definition.

Comment: @JB_Nizet I made it up, I want to display a view specific name, whatever the location

Comment: Yes it's the right approach. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13407227/63011

Comment: Then specify it using the resolve attribute of the route definition, get the current route from the $route service, and get the name from the locals of the current route. The documentation will clarify this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this - by attaching to the `$routeChangeStart` event and putting the current route name on the $rootScope.

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute']).run([
    '$rootScope',
    function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
            $rootScope.currentRoute = next;
        });
    }]);
```

Then in your HTML you could do this:

```
<span>{{currentRoute.name}}</span>
```

Comment: For clarity, shouldn't you have `angular.module('appName',[ngRoute])`?