# How to update meta tags and title on different pages in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, metadata

Following is my `index.html` page:

```
<title>Mytitle<title>
<meta name="keywords" content="abc,xyz"/>
<meta name="description" content="cde,fgh"/>
```

And i want different title, keyword and description in `signup.html` page:

(`signup.html` page rendererd under `index.html` page)

```
<title>Signup Title<title>
<meta name="keywords" content="signup, free"/>
<meta name="description" content="do signup for free"/>
```

Comment: Did you check this [how-can-i-update-meta-tags-in-angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119398/how-can-i-update-meta-tags-in-angularjs?noredirect=1&lq=1) ?

Comment: and this [Angular Dynamic meta tags in head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32152701/3623027)..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update meta tags in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119398/how-can-i-update-meta-tags-in-angularjs)

Comment: Hey @SO-user, thanks for reply. As you mention duplication question, I don't want that angular expressions `{{}}` in my  page-source as it is not google friendly

Comment: @SGRDalal, as I know, you can't achieve this in angularjs without `{{}}`

Comment: Are you using ngRoute or ui-router? Because you can pass data to each state about title, description, etc in a pretty clean way. Check this [post for ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813599/set-page-title-using-ui-router) and [this post for ngRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308020/how-to-change-page-title-in-angular-using-routeprovider)

Comment: @The.Bear there is no trick available for keyword and description meta tags in ui-router ? And Page title also not updating as i saw in page source.

Comment: @SGRDalal In angular ngRoute you have just the `title`, but not for title or description. In angular ui-router your don't have anything. As an alternative you can change the tags with pure Javascript or jquery on each route change. Read this article [angularjs and SEO](https://weluse.de/blog/angularjs-seo-finally-a-piece-of-cake.html) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications) to know more about

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can add app and controller to HTML tag (for example) and use data-binding like this:

```
<html ng-app="yourApp" ng-contoller="YourController">
<head>
  <title>{{title}}<title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="{{keywordsContent}}"/>
  <meta name="description" content="{{descriptionContent}}"/>
</head>
...
</html>
```

And in your `YourController`:

```
angular
  .module('yourApp', [])
  .controller('YourController', ['$scope', YourController]);

function YourController($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Mytitle";
  $scope.keywordsContent = "abc,xyz";
  $scope.descriptionContent = "cde,fgh";
}
```

And you can control this scope variables from child controller using `$scope.$parent`:

```
angular
  .module('yourApp', [])
  .controller('ChildController', ['$scope', ChildController]);

function ChildController($scope) {
  $scope.$parent.title = "Changed Title";
  $scope.$parent.keywordsContent = "Changed Keywords";
  $scope.$parent.descriptionContent = "Changed Description";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Commercial Suicide, Thank you so much for your respone. but I don't want angular expression `{{title}}`  in my page source if i view page source. Let me know if is there any other way.

Comment: @SGRDalal, I'm not sure that the any other way exists in angularjs. But I think that you can do it via pure javascript or jQuery by getting the element and changing attributes content. Is it OK for you?