# is there away to set page's title in angularAMD like it is in $routeProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider, angular-amd

I am trying to achive something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when("/home", angularAMD.route({
    title: 'Home',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'testCtrl'
}))
```

Like in this post about $routeProvider [How to dynamically change header based on angularjs partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view) (the second unacepted answer but seem to be better answer)

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
  title: 'Home',
  templateUrl: '/Assets/Views/Home.html',
  controller: 'HomeController'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code `below the app.config()`

```
  app.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function($rootScope, $route) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
            document.title = $route.current.title;
        });
    }]);
```

**And Layout View:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>Default title</title>
```

*No need to bind, no need to use {{}}.*

Comment: Thanks for the document title!

Comment: @LinhPham: OffTopic: If possible try to look over the issue (not solved yet)
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288001/how-to-use-chart-js-with-angular-chart-using-requirejs

Comment: Something messed with my mobile, it does solved issue in a way. Thanks again

Comment: Ok. Please look over the question that I have mentioned in previous comment. I am having problem there, try to suggest something.

Comment: I already added comment there. Check it out and provide some more info after applied what I suggest in the comment :)

Comment: Yes. I am looking over it. Will try whatever you suggest...Thanks.