# Set page title dynamically, use information from scope

Tags: angularjs, routes, page-title

I would like to set page titles in AngularJS dynamically per route, and the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13407227/353337 has served me well.
Now, instead of having the page title say "Article", I would like to display the actual title of the article, i.e., I'd like to use information from the current scope.

How would this be possible?

Comment: On the same question you link, look at this answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17898250/4555964. And I would incorporate the comment by Kristo Aun on this answer about using routeChangeStart instead of routeChangeSuccess for setting the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible way of doing this is emitting an event from the controller.

Here's how to do it:

### Index page (stays the same)

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="RootCtrl">
    <title data-ng-bind="htmlTitle"></title>
    ...
```

### Root app controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('RootCtrl', function(){
   $scope.$on('changedPage', function changedPage(event, pageTitle){
      $scope.htmlTitle = pageTitle;
   });
});
```

### Any route controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('HomeCtrl', function(){
   var pageTitle = "Build this string however you want";
   $scope.$emit('changedPage', pageTitle);
});
```