# How do I add page-title using angular?

Tags: angularjs

I need to dynamically load the page title using angular. What is the best way of doing this? Any ideas could be very useful.

Comment: Define a controller for the page and define the title inside the scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be quite easy if you are defining your controller at the body level. If thats the case you can declare and define a scope variable like pageTitle and use it to show the page title. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12506795/1182982)

If not, and if you are using routes to select controller based on the routes you could still do this using the rootScope like hows its [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13407227/1182982).

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])

myApp.config(
    ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            title: 'Home',
            templateUrl: '/Assets/Views/Home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/Product/:id', {
            title: 'Product',
            templateUrl: '/Assets/Views/Product.html',
            controller: 'ProductController'
        });
    }]);

myApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
}]);
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title ng-bind="'myApp &mdash; ' + title">myApp</title>
```

Edit :

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view/13407227#13407227) on SO has very good answers and is similar to what your are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html ng-app="app" ng-controller="titleCtrl">
   <head>
     <title>{{ title }}</title>
 ...
```

Inside your controller

```
app.controller("titleCtrl",function($scope){
     $scope.title="hello page";
});
```

Second way for different pages:-

You could define controller at the  level.

```
 <html ng-app="app" ng-controller="titleCtrl">
   <head>
     <title>{{ Page.title() }}</title>
 ...
```

You create service: Page and modify from controllers.

```
app.factory('Page', function() {
   var title = 'default';
   return {
     title: function() { return title; },
     setTitle: function(newTitle) { title = newTitle }
   };
});
```

Inject Page and Call 'Page.setTitle()' from controllers.

for example:-

```
app.controller("pageonectrl",funtion($scope,Page){

Page.setTitle("pageone");

});

app.controller("pagetwoctrl",funtion($scope,Page){

Page.setTitle("pagetwo");

});
```

PS:-Second one is more efficient for practical purpose :)

Credit:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12506795/1632286