# Multiple routes sharing one controller, how about different titles?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm re-writing an app using angularjs.
Until today each route of the app had each own controller and a title as well for the prowser using a service like that:

```
  myApp.factory('PageTitle', function(){
     var title = 'Default title';
     return {
       title: function() { return title; },
       setTitle: function(newTitle) { title = newTitle; }
     };
  });
```

which the i use in the controller like that:

```
PageTitle.setTitle(TitleVariable);
```

That worked perfectly until now.
I need as i said to re-write my app to have only one controller for all the routes.

So i'm trying to run a function looking at the route change with the current route path to update the title (which i forgot to mention is a dynamic information, so i cannot add a title variable in the routes file i guess) but it just not working.

What is the correct way to achieve that?

My routes looking that that:

```
  myApp.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!'); 


$routeProvider

  // route for the home page
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'views/homepage.html'
  })

  // route for the home page
  .when('/home/:pageSlug/', {
    templateUrl : 'views/homepage.html'
  })
```

etc.

I'm calling the controller in the index.html file on header like:

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="appCtrl">
```

And i'm getting the title like that:

```
<title data-ng-bind="PageTitle.title()"></title>
```

Comment: Please refer to this stack-overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view

Comment: @YashikaGarg i did read it already but it seems there only the solution i have already with different controller for each route.