# Angular Js Access Title from $routeProvider on each View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there is any possible way to get the title attribute into header always when the route changed

Example:

```
when('/newsletter', {
            title: 'News Letter',
            templateUrl:'app/Views/segment/newsletter.html'
})
```

When this route comes the view is newsletter and i need to show the title as newsletter in Header Newsletter Tab

Comment: Yes. This should work. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view) for more details. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Currently i am using $rootscope.title in each controller and your suggestion is what i am lookin for, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to expose `$route` service to the view in either main controller (topmost) or in run block (better):

```
app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', function($route, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$route = $route;
}]);
```

Then in any view you can display current title:

```
<header>
    <h1>{{ $route.current.title }}</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$route' of undefined

Comment: It was my injector error this method is simple and good thanks @dfsq

Comment: to access to $rootscope from a view it is `<h1>{{ $root.$route.current.title }}</h1>` or i am wrong ?

Comment: @AlainIb No, it's `$route.current.title`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I always used in my project `$root.$route.current.title` style, maybe both work. for example if you have the same variable name in $rootscope and $scope

Comment: @AlainIb The reason why it works is because every scope object has a property reference `$root` pointing to the root scope. But in our case it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a root scope variable named "title" and change it in your controller by doing `$rootScope.title = 'new title';` Or better, you can have this done in the `resolve` option in router, for more information, please click: [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)