# Controller inside state provider working for ncybreadcrumb but not for pagetitle

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to output the name of a folder both as ncybreadcrumb label and as HTML page title, using a controller which populates a scope variable. See the code below:

```
state('messenger.folder', {
    url: '/:folder',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {label: '{{folderLabel}}' },
    data: {pageTitle: '{{folderLabel}}'},

    controller: function($scope,$stateParams) {
      $scope.folderLabel = $stateParams.folder;
      }
    }).
```

The strange thing is: It works perfectly for ncybreadcrumb, but not for page title: page-title is always empty.

Does anyone have an idea why this is the case and how to fix it?

Comment: How do you take `pageTitle`?

Comment: There's a controller for all states, which sets a scope variable "title" to `$state.$current.data.pageTitle` And that works. If I change `pageTitle: '{{folderLabel}}'` to `pageTitle: '>>{{folderLabel}}<<'`, I get ">><<". So, the string is passed correctly, but `folderLabel` is not inserted.

Answer (score 0):

It could work for ncyBreadcrumb because the 3rd party lib angular-breadcrumb do special handling there.

I find a work round for dynamic title here:

[How to dynamically change header based on AngularJS partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view)