# Head tags filled up dynamically with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meta, angularjs-bindings

I would like to know if it's possible to change the values of some HEAD tags dynamically with Angular. An example would be this transformation:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#2F7DCA">
```

to:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="{{ color }}">
```

This is the theory but I would like to know if someone has tried it and it works, or if this is not the way, how to do it. I am not able to test it right now but I need to know it before starting to code. If it's possible to do it, I would appreciate some examples of how to manipulate other HEAD tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `ng-bind` attribute (the curly braces may break the code you use to apply the color when the page first loads).
Have a look at this post: [How to dynamically change header based on AngularJS partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view) 
They use it for the title but you can use this for `meta` tags as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it is.

```
/**** ONE controller ****/
$scope.color = 'red';   

/**** Global ****/
$rootScope.color = 'red';
$scope.$root.color = 'red';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but only if the `meta` is in scope of your `ng-app`, so something like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head ng-controller="headCtrl">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="{{ color }}">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script>
        angular.module("myApp", [])
            .controller("headCtrl", function($scope) {
                $scope.color = "#2F7DCA";
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```