# How to change the page title that is being set in controller when using ui -router

Tags: angularjs

I have a module in my application which shares same controller and services for two views under it. However my view 1 page title is set to be Home in the controller's init function like this

```
//module.js

import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import 'd3';
import 'jquery';

// Controllers
import controller from './moduleoneController.js';

let path = './modules/moduleone/';


let modone = angular.module('modone', [
    'ui.router'
])

    // Controllers
    .controller('moduleoneCtrl', moduleoneCtrl)


    // Routes
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('moduleone', {
            url: '/moduleone',
            controller: 'moduleoneCtrl',
            templateUrl: path + 'views/one.html',
        })
        .state('view2',{
            url: '/view2',
            controller: 'moduleoneCtrl',
            templateUrl: path + 'views/two.html',
        });
    }]);

export default moduleone;

//in my controller title is being set like this
    this.init = function () {
                someService.setPageTitle('Home');       
            };

    init();

//html 

<div header-text="{{oneCtrl.title}}"></div>
```

but when I am using this controller for view 2 I cannot change the title to the one I wanted, How do we change it in such cases ?

Comment: please post some code

Comment: see this SO answser: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view)

Comment: @JoshA Those solutions did not work for me !

Comment: @RamanSahasi I have posted some code. Please take a look at it !