# How to change the page title using a variable in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I am changing my title dynamically in AngularJs, using the following code:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            title: 'My Tagline',
            controller : 'IndexController',
            templateUrl : 'static/app_partials/index.html'
        })
        .when('/categories/:categoryPk/', {
            title: $scope.category.name,
            controller : 'CategoryController',
            templateUrl : 'static/app_partials/category.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo : '/' });
}]);
```

**Html**

```
<title ng-bind="'My Brand - ' + title">My Brand</title>
```

So, for the `IndexController`, the title is just a simple string, so this method works nicely. However, for my `CategoryController`, I want the title to be generated from a variable, specifically, `$scope.category.name`, which I initialize in my controller code. How can I do this? Any help?

Comment: You can also find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view

Answer (score 3):

use `ng-bind-template` as follow:

```
<title ng-bind-template="My Brand - {{$root.title}}">My Brand</title>
```

Comment: also have to remove `title: $scope.category.name,` from routing config...there is no `$scope` there

Comment: And then how will put my variable as the title from the controller?

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee You could do it inside the `routeChangeSuccess` even handler

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ng-meta](https://github.com/vinaygopinath/ngMeta) to set dynamic meta tags in your AngularJS single page application