# AngularJS SPA page title

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I am developing a website(SPA) in AngularJS.

I set page titles dynamically:

```
<title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>
```

for each page I have unique page titles which should be generated base on user input.

everything works fine and I have read that there is no SEO problem with this method. but the problem is that in browsers Bookmark tab, I see "{{ pageTitle }}" instead on the title of the website. I know that it's because of the browsers behavior but is there a way to fix it?

one solution that came in my mind is to use the following code instead:

```
<title ng-bind="pageTitle">My actual website title</title>
```

how good is this?

Comment: most people go for [ng-bind in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view)

Comment: very interesting question. which browser you are using?

Comment: @RakeshBurbure any browser. no difference. since they all get the title from the HTML tag. not the title generated by JS.