# Loader screen in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to show up a loader screen while the main page of my application is loading, I'd like  something similar to what the [AngularJS Blog](http://blog.angularjs.org/) does (which I think that's pretty cool), I've seen the documentation for [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak) but it looks like that just hides the content while it's loading the application preventing to display {{}}, but how can I manage show my layout or "main page" until that's fully loaded?

which could be the best way to implement a solution according to that use case?
I'm not sure but are a directive, http interceptor, defer a route, ngCloak, good candidates for the solution?

thanks

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947295/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-loader-animation-while-scripts-and-resources?rq=1?

Comment: no men, looking at that now

Comment: the thing about angular-promise -tracking is that it only uses $http calls and I'm more confortable about using $resource, but it seems like "Make everything hidden with ng-cloak CSS, and make a spinner shown by default. Then remove the spinner once angular fully loads. " could work, let me try that out

Comment: is there an opposite behavior to ng-cloak, in the post isn't clear enough how to acomplish the steps mentioned above.

Comment: How about the second answer to that question? It looks like it would work and seems fairly simple to implement.

Comment: let's say that I have a div that contains a spinner and a message, and below that I have another div using the ng-cloak directive, how do I disappear the first div after the second one is rendered?

Comment: use `ng-hide="loaded"` and after second div is rendered do `$scope.loaded = true`

Comment: it worked that way I created a contoller reference it at the last controller in end of the page and it worked like a charm!

Comment: my be you searching for someting like this?
http://jsbin.com/EMUliKAc/1/edit, (the timeout is simulation loading process)