# Resolve before showing the home page of an office addin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ms-office, office-js

I am trying to use `angularjs` framework to implement an office addin.

In `Home.html`, the content is up to `$scope.condition`

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-show="condition">
        part1
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!condition">
        part2
    </div>
</div>
```

In `Home.js`, I have the follows. Note that the value of `$scope.condition` can change in the runtime.

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        app.initialize();
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['appAng'])
        })
    });
}

var appAng = angular.module('appAng', []);

appAng.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.condition = ...
}
```

The problem is, when the addin is loaded for the first time, before the value of `$scope.condition` is calculated, both `part1` and `part2` are shown for a very short time. The time is short, but the first impression is not good.

If it was a website, we could use, for example, `resolve` of `angular-ui-router` to make sure `$scope.condition` is calculated before displaying the page.

Does anyone have any good idea to improve this in an office addin? Note that I don't have a server behind for this addin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak). You need to add this `CSS`:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

And then add the `ng-cloak` attribute or class to your template:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-show="condition">
        part1
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!condition">
        part2
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, keep this quote from the docs in mind:

> For the best result, the angular.js script must be loaded in the head
>   section of the html document; alternatively, the css rule above must
>   be included in the external stylesheet of the application.

Comment: I see... It does help for addin! I'm thinking of using `ng-cloak` for my website (bootstrap + angularjs + ui-router) as well. As the controller is in `$stateProvider.state('home', { url: '/home', controller: 'MainCtrl' ... })`, where should I put `ng-cloak`? I tried to put `<body ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak><ui-view></ui-view></body>`, but it does not seem to be better than before.

Comment: Check my update in the answer. I would try to put it in the `<ui-view>` element, but I think `<body>` should work fine anyway. This is worth taking a look if none of those changes work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302344/ng-cloak-doesnt-help-for-angular-ui-router-for-hiding-elements-while-template-p

Comment: OK... The problem of my website is not `ng-show` or `ng-if`, etc., it just has some very slight flicker effect, I don't know if `ng-cloak` is supposed to solve that, I don't see obvious improvement after adding `ng-cloak`...