# Initially hide elements when using angular.js

Tags: angularjs

In the example below I do not want the values "A" og "B" to be visible until JavaScript has been loaded and `$scope.displayA` has been set by the return of some ajax call.

```
<span ng-show="displayA">A</span>
<span ng-hide="displayA">B</span>
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249768/angularjs-ng-cloak-ng-show-elements-blink

Comment: ok. I thought it would be enough for you to see that you needed two things: `ng-cloak` and a css-rule.

Comment: (I deleted my previous comment by mistake:) The answer to the other question you are referring to provides additional and valuable information, but it does not answer my question, which is how do I achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use ng-cloak on them.
Link to docs:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak