# Ng-Show causing flicker

Tags: angularjs

I have tried the following, but am still getting a flicker when using ng-show: [Angularjs - ng-cloak/ng-show elements blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249768/angularjs-ng-cloak-ng-show-elements-blink)

I am using a template to load my top nav as follows:

```
<div data-ng-controller="userInfoCtrl">
   <a href="#!home">Home</a>
<a href="#!add-item">Add Item</a>
<a href="#!settings" data-ng-show="display">Settings</a>
```

Here is my controller:

```
   // User Info
appControllers.controller('userInfoCtrl', ['$scope', 'appAdminCheck', function ($scope, appAdminCheck) {

    // Set value for using ng-show/ng-hide
    appAdminCheck().then(function (isAdmin) {
        if (isAdmin == true) {
            $scope.display = true;
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Show us some more code. It is not sufficient. Where is ng-show ?

Comment: @squiroid right there `<a href="#!settings" data-ng-show="display">Settings</a>`

Comment: does `display` has set to false initially, or use ng-if will solve your issue..

Comment: @kode is this safari specific issue for ionic-framework?

Comment: @Kode you didn't provide enough information to solve your issue :-p

Comment: And you did include the css rule for ng-cloak?

Comment: Yes I did include the CSS rule for ng-cloak not work. The issue is occurring cross browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. I had loaded the navigation as a template in each view, so when I changed routes, it was causing a flicker on the ng-show item. Moving the template into my index page resolved the issue, as it is loaded once. Example:

```
 <%--Container for HTML, inclusive of AngularJS App and responsive aspects--%>
<div class="container">

    <%--Include top menu--%>
    <div data-ng-include="'../Templates/topmenu.html'"></div>

    <%--Load Angular Views--%>
    <div data-ng-view></div>

    <%--Footer of page. Could be an include as well--%>
    <hr>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

try this,

use `ng-class` with `style='visibility: hidden'`,

```
<a href="#!settings" style="visibility: hidden" ng-class='{forceShow: display}'>Settings</a>
```

`style="visibility: hidden"` hides the `<a>` initially then, when `display` comes to `true` class `forceShow` will add to the `<a>` by `ng-class`,

and force `visibility: visible` when `$scope.display == true`,

```
<style>
    .forceShow {
      visibility: visible !important;
    }
</style>
```

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0bpvC57NPi131noiXZQi?p=preview)

Comment: I know it will work, but why wee need hack? while we provided ng-show directive? can you please elaborate the reason.

Comment: I am agree with pankaj parkar :-p

Comment: @k.Toress did you able to reproduce the above issue, see this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/1xbWnKEfokk5fr1I0qLk?p=preview , how could you fix this issue without reproducing it..

Comment: lol :p, when compiling a directive its takes sometime to attach to the relevant controller, and bind the directives to the scope, if you put a css its will affect the element at first before the directives like `ng-show` or `ng-hide` or something else.

Comment: This still flickers everytime I go to another route, could it be because I have included the links as a template in each route?