# Preventing Angular Template from Initial Display

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following an online example.  However, it doesn't work quite the way I had hoped it would.  Now, I could easily do this with jQuery and a class, but I am trying to do it the "Angular Way".

The Angular Template for my tags is initially displaying.  Once the scope starts to process, then it hides & the tags come-in as expected when binding.

**Q: How do I prevent the Angular Template form initially displaying?**
[image]

**UPDATE:**
Applying "ng-bind" only changes the nature of the problem.  It doesn't solve the problem.
[image]

**MY MARKUP LOOKS LIKE:**

```
<div ng-controller="BlogsIndexController">
    <div class="tags-cloud tags-cloud-category" ng-show="isShown">
        <div class="tag" ng-repeat="category in categories">
            <a href="#" data-iso-sort="iso-sort-category-{{category.SortKey}}">{{category.Name}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MY CONTROLLER LOOKS LIKE:**

```
// CONTROLLER
application.controller('BlogsIndexController', function ($scope, $http, categoryTagsDataService) {
    var vm = this;

    // Internal
    vm.on = {
        databind: {
            categories: function () {
                var categories = categoryTagsDataService.list()
                categories.success(function (data) {
                    $scope.categories = data;
                    $scope.isShown = true;
                });
            }
        }
    };
    vm.databind = function () {
        vm.on.databind.categories();
    };

    // Scope
    $scope.isShown = false;
    $scope.categories = [];

    // Initialize
    vm.databind();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ngBind="category.Name"` instead of `{{category.Name}}`:

```
<a href="#" data-iso-sort="iso-sort-category-{{category.SortKey}}"
   ng-bind="category.Name"></a>
```

> It is preferable to use ngBind instead of {{ expression }} if a template is momentarily displayed by the browser in its raw state before Angular compiles it. Since ngBind is an element attribute, it makes the bindings invisible to the user while the page is loading.

More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind).

**Update 1:**

I've never used `ngCloak`, but [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) say that it may help you:

```
<a href="#" data-iso-sort="iso-sort-category-{{category.SortKey}}"
   ng-bind="category.Name" ng-cloak></a>
```

**Update 2:**

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13276214/183267) answer and it seems that you need also to add the next CSS rule:

```
/* 
Allow angular.js to be loaded in body, hiding cloaked elements until 
templates compile.  The !important is important given that there may be 
other selectors that are more specific or come later and might alter display.  
*/
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you very much.