# AngularJs elements flicker

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having difficulties making ng-cloak work. I've tried everything on this page:
[ng-cloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249768/angularjs-ng-cloak-ng-show-elements-blink/13276214#13276214)

I have a ui-view containing 2 divs. The divs are mutually exclusive. I want to show only one of them. I'm trying to control this by using the ng-show / ng-hide pair.

```
  <div ng-controller="app.overviewController" ng-cloak>        
       <div name="a" ng-show="isFirst">
                     ...content
       </div>

       <div name="b" ng-hide="isFirst">
                     ...content
       </div>
   </div>
```

"isFirst" is being set with a call to a WebApi method, in the controller attached to this view.
I have a hard time figuring out if i'm missing something. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no `ng-cloak` shown in your code and we have no idea how `isFirst` is set. We can't help you troubleshoot `ng-cloak` if you don't show all the relevant code and css used. A demo that replicates problem would also help

Answer (score 0):

As stated here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak
You have to use ngCloak either as attribute or class

Here are the two approaches.

```
<div name="a" ng-cloak>...</div>
<div name="a" class="ng-cloak">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying it during the page load time then you can achieve it like this:

```
<div ng-show="false">
Page is loading...  
</div>
```

In your above code snippets, I guess may be the `isFirst` variable should be initialized at the time of declaration.

Also try this way.

```
<div name="a" ng-show="isFirst">
     ...content
</div>

<div name="b" ng-hide="!isFirst">
   ...content
</div>
```