# ng-show content blinks during page load though it is not truthy and ng-cloak doesn't work with FF

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, angular-directive

```
<div ng-show="IsExists" ng-cloak>
 <span>The value is exists</span>
</div>
```

Then i have added the below lines in my app.css

But still i am seeing the initial flickering of ng-show block

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

The above stuff is not working on Firefox.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249768/angularjs-ng-cloak-ng-show-elements-blink?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-if` it won't be loaded into the DOM at all then.
`ng-show` applies `display: none`
`ng-if` removes from the DOM.

Comment: no luck, still i am getting the flickering during page lod after i have tried with ng-if.

Comment: Apologies. I'll try some plunkrs tomorrow :)