# Two toggling elements with ngHide flash on screen momentarily

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a couple of containers that show text based on a scope property:

```
<style>
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak{
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
<a ng-hide="show===false" ng-cloak>item 1</a>
<a ng-hide="show===true"  ng-cloak>item 2</a>
<span ng-click="toggle()">toggle</span> 
//js
var app = angular.module('appy', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.toggle = function(){
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  };
});
```

https://jsbin.com/numaxiroka/edit?html,js,output

This simple example works in the JSBIN, but on my page the content "item 1" and "item 2" both flash momentarily on the screen. What could I be doing incorrectly that would make both elements appear briefly?

I've been using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249768/angularjs-ng-cloak-ng-show-elements-blink) for reference.

Comment: As a start it would improve things to simply have:
 `ng-show="show"`  for the first item, and `ng-hide="show"` for the second.

Comment: Are the ngcloak styles loaded before your content on your actual page?

Comment: @Dan I think you lost some text there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st thing I'd suggest you to do is, place `ng-cloak` there on `body` instead of each anchor. So that will help to hide `angular uncompiled` content (`{{}}`) to appear any where inside body.

---

If you are just trying to show anchor, then I'd say that do use **`ng-bind`** to render their inner text like below

**Markup**

```
<a ng-bind="show? 'item 1' : 'item 2'" href="{{myHref(show)}}"></a>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.myHref = function(){
   if(show) 
      return 'something/someaction1' 
   else 
      return 'something/someaction2' ;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  you've bound `show`, but then I don't see you using it anywhere. Then your `myHref` method always returns the same string..?

Comment: @thomas I did that just form demonstration.. First thing you should try placing `ng-cloak` over body element..

Comment: Ultimately I did not end up using this, but it is nonetheless a clean solution. Thanks much!

Comment: @thomas may I know what you ended up using ?