# How to hide <ui-view> when it render?

Tags: angularjs

I need to hide content of `<ui-view></ui-view>` when it render (including images). What is the easiest way for it in Angular 1.5 and jQuery?

Cool if it will without vendor moudules.

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13276214/5954939.

Summary - `ng-cloak` attribute will hide rendered elements (by applying relevant CSS).

Answer (score 0):

You can play with css like this:

```
[ui-view].ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-leave {
    transition: z-index .5s; }

[ui-view].ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-leave-active {
    z-index: 0; }

[ui-view].ng-leave, [ui-view].ng-enter-active {
    z-index: 1; }
```

As an option, you can change z-index with opacity.