# Animate repeating data on two way binding with css in async process

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, vue.js

When we are using, the `v-for` in vue.js or `ng-repeat` in angular, I am not sure when the empty array/object gets filled up with data in after async request (lets say ajax or timeout) the data suddenly flashes even though there is animation added.

One solution I could think of is with some time interval push the data one after another by looping, which is ok.

Is there any way I can achieve with css animation only for repeating, for the repeated data to appear one after another.

Ex: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZKQWY

Comment: You will need to use the interval.

Comment: slow down the animation

Comment: Without assuming too much, your problem seems to be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249768/angularjs-ng-cloak-ng-show-elements-blink#13276214

Specifically, in your case, the view is not refreshed in the same time interval that the data becomes available.

Comment: @charlietfl, slowing down animation won't work, but may be creating class in loop, like 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s ... and defining css property with transition 1s, 2s, 3s might, which is again with limit of n (number of times its looping) which cannot be declared in css repetitively.

Comment: Could you clarify on what it is you want?

Comment: @EricGuan Is there any way I can achieve with css animation for the repeated data to appear one after another.

Comment: I don't think so. You can with Vue (aka javascript), and the official docs provides an example https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Staggering-List-Transitions